# Use of hibernate.reveng.xml

Tags: hibernate

In my application , i am using integration of `Hibernate` and `jsf` , in `hibernate-configuration` we used to create

**Hibernate.cfg.xml**

- To implement the connection with database and for session factory

**(pojo class).hbm.xml**

- Which contains the Table columns and other table properties for creating the pojo objects

*And we have another one*

**hibernate.reveng.xml**

- Actually what is the use of it in application , i have tried without this xml too the data's are adding perfectly in database and  the application works perfectly.

I just want know something more about this `hibernate.reveng.xml` ..

Answer (score 1):

The file `hibernate.reveng.xml` is used to configure reverse engineering (rev-eng).  A description is [here](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/latest/en/hibernatetools/html/reverseengineering.html). The Ant task is documented [here](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Developer_Studio/4.0/html/Hibernate_Tools_Reference_Guide/ch05s02.html).